# TImeBased Trigger in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, triggers

I have sqLite Table like this

```
+----------+----------+
| FireTime | DeviceId |
+----------+----------+
|    08:00 | 00000000 |
+----------+----------+
```

i want to create a trigger which accepts mDeviceId parameter from user and checks for 
mDeviceId entry is there in table or not this trigger must be fire on 8 : 00

How can is do so ? can any one suggest me that

Answer (score 1):

Use [BroadcasteReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) and set its trigger time to what you want...

Answer (score 0):

According To my knowledge trigger cannot be execute on schedule.
trigger is always execute after/Before some operation on database.
u can't specify time on it.

oracle and sqlsever use "sql job scheduler" for this.

there is no similar implementation in SQLite according to my knowledge.

you can implement mechanism by hard code.